# Tags disappeared from https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

I'm not able to get the list of unanswered Tags after clicking on the Unanswered question all what I'm getting is a List of unanswered question with random tags and I can't specify question with a desired tag.

what I'm getting now: **No Tags at the right**!!
[image]

how things work in the past:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to still be here, albeit perhaps by a different route; if you click on a tag you're interested in seeing unanswered questions for:

[image]

and then, on the new page, click the 'unanswered' tab, you should get a list of unanswered questions within that tag:

[image]

To then filter that list to those including other tags in which you're interested, [css](/questions/tagged/css) in my case, scroll down and click on that tag:

[image]

Which will then, obviously I suppose, show unanswered questions from both the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) and [css](/questions/tagged/css) tags (in my example, anyway):

[image]

Comment: yes it's working like this. I also get it work now with the usual way I think this is do to a bug cache

Answer (score 0):

This is a Cache bug, I get all think right after waiting a little more and refreshing the web page.